# Flutter - User Images from database aligned like the example

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I am working on a small project trying to learn flutter. I have card events pulled from my database and I would like to visually show current users that are joined. I a similar way like the image bellow.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My biggest question is the frontend part of how to arrange them like that.

I already have the full database.

The structure is every Event has an ID and rest of the info, then it has a group which is all users who are joined and then each of those users [1][2][3] has their user details and userimage: 'avatar1example.png'is one of them. I know how to pull the image id and connect it with the imageasset (images are preset avatars not user uploads) so my question is mostly the frontend part + the number.

EDIT: After using the code below i got this.

```
Widget userImages (data) {
      int limmit = 3;
    List<Widget> _children = [];
    int index = 0;
    for (var element in data.users) {
      if (index < limmit) {
        Widget image = Image(
          image: AssetImage(element.userDetails.imageUrl),
        );
        if (index != 0) {
          _children.add(Positioned(
            child: image,
            left: index * 20.0,
            top: 0,
          ));
        } else {
          _children.add(image);
        }
      } else {
        int number = data.users.length - limmit;
        _children.add(Positioned(
          left: index * 20.0,
          top: 0,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            child: Center(child: Text('+$number')),
            radius: 15,
          ),
        ));
        break;
      }
      index++;
    };
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 30,
      child: Stack(
        children: _children,
      ),
    );
  }
```

And i use it like this

```
Container(
                                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.pink),
                                                        child: Row(
                                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                                              MainAxisAlignment
                                                                  .center,
                                                          children: [
                                                            Container(
                                                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                                                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                                                child: cardDescJoined(
                                                                    snapshot.data[
                                                                        index])),
                                                            Container(
                                                              height: 80,
                                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.yellow),
                                                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                                                              child: userImages(snapshot.data[index].group)
                                                            ),
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this widget:

```
_buildImages() {
    int limmit = 3;
    List<Widget> _children = [];
    int index = 0;
    for (var element in _images) {
      if (index < limmit) {
        Widget image = Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white)),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            foregroundImage: AssetImage(element),
            radius: 15,
          ),
        );
        if (index != 0) {
          _children.add(Positioned(
            child: image,
            left: index * 20,
            top: 0,
          ));
        } else {
          _children.add(image);
        }
      } else {
        int number = _images.length - limmit;
        _children.add(Positioned(
          left: index * 20,
          top: 0,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white)),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              child: Center(child: Text('+$number')),
              radius: 15,
            ),
          ),
        ));
        break;
      }
      index++;
    }
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 30 + 2, // image height + 2 white border width
      child: Stack(
        children: _children,
      ),
    );
  }
```

and use it like this:

```
_buildImages(),
```

also remember `_images` is list of your profile image.

[image]

Comment: its seems to work but I am getting Renderflex Overflow on both side by about 86 and 186 pixels, i can use SVGs or PNGs for images, I think I should wrap them some way so they shrink.

Comment: can you show me how do you use it ?and use it inside what widget?

Comment: I edited my question to show current changes.

Comment: Ignore the 0 joined that is currently pinging a part of database that isn't updated, each event defaults to min of 1 user which is the one that created it. I show the right image from the database i check as well and it loads the asset.

Comment: Ignore I fixed it thank.